# How to write schema if i want categories and sub-categories in mongoose

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

Hope you guy's doing well

so my question is how to design categories and sub-categories schema in mongodb.
for example: OLX have different categories let's choose Mobile phone and then further it shows brands of phones. This type of schema i want to write so that it's easily to retrieve data and easily to handle all the stuff.

Any suggestion, code will be highly appreciable
Thanks In Advance

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/schema/chapter8/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.